# Need a CURL binary availble inside kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, curl, kubernetes, alpine-linux

**I would like to sh myself inside a kubernetes pod and execute a CURL command. Unfortunatly I can't find anywhere a working image with curl availble (and compatible with kubernetes)...**

1. I tried some docker images with Alpine and CURL but each time it ended with crashLoopBackOff. I guess it means the container exited because the docker image exits after executing itself...
2. I also tried using the image of alpine and ubuntu alone but each time it also ended with crashloopBackOff.
3. I manage to exec in a few images but it never had CURL installed and neither APT-GET or APK were working.

To exec into a container I'm doing a simple `kubectl exec -it POD_ID /bin/bash`

*Does someone knows of a minimal docker image that contains a CURL binary and wont crash in kubernetes ?*

PS: This is for testing purpose so it does not need to be rock solid or anything

Thx

---

UPDATE 1 
This is the yaml I use to deploy all potential image :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blue
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: blue
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blue-website
        image: SOME_IMAGE:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.1
            memory: 200
```

I don't think that its broken because it works on certain image.

Comment: You are getting `crashLoopBackOff` because of some reason. Can you share yaml file that you have tried?

Comment: @EmruzHossain I updated my question :-)

Comment: You’re probably looking for `kubectl run`.  Kubernetes’s general model isn’t to have idle pods sitting around waiting for users to exec into them; if a container starts up, has nothing to do, and immediately exits, you’ll get the `crashLoopBackOff` state.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah that what I though too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You getting `CrashLoopBackOff` because container completes after starting as it does not have any task to process. Easy workaround is to run a command in the container to keep it running indefinitely. So that you can exec into the container and run curl.

Here, is modified yaml to do this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blue
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: blue
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blue-website
        image: scrapinghub/httpbin:latest
        command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.1
            memory: 200
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. It works ! Httpbin has indeed a curl binary availble and the .yaml works. Though I would point out that httpbin seems to be working without using the "command" key. I guess it means that httpbin doesn't exits by itself.

Answer (score 19):

You can skip the manifest and use `kubectl run` to spin up one of these pods on demand.
i.e.

```
kubectl run curl -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl -- sh
```

This would create a deployment named `curl` from the `curlimages/curl` image and give you an interactive (`-it`) shell inside it. When you exit, the deployment will be deleted (`--rm`).

Comment: Thx for your answer. It works well ! I would prefer having a .yaml though :-)

Comment: Understood. I prefer spinning stuff like this up on demand because with a yaml manifest you usually have to do something like `sleep 3000` to make sure the process doesn't just end right away. Seems hacky to me and the container might exit when you are in the middle of something. Plus then you don't have pods hanging around when you're not actively using them, but to each their own.

Comment: The `tutum/curl` image is not available anymore, but this still works with the `curlimages/curl` image.

Comment: edited the original answer

Comment: thanks for that, very useful but how to run this command in a different namespace?

Comment: add --namespace <my-namespace>
or -n <my-namespace> to the command. the same is true for almost any kubectl command.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this image `nightfury1204/alpine-curl`

I created above image for my own testing purpose.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: curl
  labels:
    name: curl
spec:
  serviceName: "curl"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: curl
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: curl
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: curl
        image: nightfury1204/alpine-curl
        command:
          - "sh"
          - "-c"
          - >
            while true; do
              sleep 3600;
            done
```

To exec into the pod use this `kubectl exec -it curl-0 sh`

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunatly deploying this .yaml is not creating any pods resulting in the command line not working.

Comment: This is incredibly useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `byrnedo/alpine-curl` image from https://hub.docker.com/r/byrnedo/alpine-curl/.
Also it's not neccessary to have `latest` tag in the deployment. It works without it, just

```
containers:
  - name: blue-website
    image: byrnedo/alpine-curl
```

Comment: Its not working. I get crashLoopbackOff. Its probably because the entrypoint exits at one point resulting in the container crashing.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Then just replace the docker image with `tutum/curl` as suggested by switchboard.op above. Yeah the reason is that there is no running process in a container so pod just stops and therefore you have crashLoopbackOff. Either you have sleep command in the deployment spec along with some simple image like `byrnedo/alpine-curl` or use `tutum/curl` which is a server listnening on port 80 and it's got curl installed https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/hello-world/